# Point type in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I found this regarding Point type in Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html

Is there the SQLAlchemy version of this?

I am storing values in this manner: (40.721959482, -73.878993913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it's a slight modification of Mohammad's answer.

Yes I need to add a point column via geo/sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
# and import others

class Shop(db.Model):
    # other fields
    coordinates = Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

On my PostGIS/Gres and PGloader side, since I'm loading from a csv that formats my latitude and longitude points as: `"(40.721959482, -73.878993913)"` I needed to do a macro in vim for all of my entries (there's a lot) in order to force that column to adhere to how points are created in PostGIS, so I turned the csv column into `point(40.721959482 -73.878993913)`, then upon table creation set the location column with the datatype as geometry(point) `location geometry(point)`.

Comment: Clarification: This is only true if you have the PostGIS extension enabled.  SQLAlchemy or GeoAlchemy2 don't seem to support the Point type in Posgres without the extension

Comment: AArias's answer below should be the accepted as this requires an additional library that could bloat your codebase

Comment: Could I use the `Geometry` class in Alembic migrations, or do I need to write custom SQL for migrations?
For example, can I do this:
`op.create_table('gps', sa.Column('coordinates', Geometry('POINT'), nullable=False), ...)`

Answer (score 9):

You can use [geoalchemy2](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/) whis is an extension to sqlalchemy and can be used with flask-sqlalchemy too.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
# and import others

class Shop(db.Model):
    # other fields
    coordinates = Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

Comment: In Posgresql would the datatype be Point, or will it be geometry(Point)? I can load in my csv file no problem if I set the column Location to Point datatype (Location Point) upon table creation. When I do Location geometry(Point) (I was looking at PostGIS documentation) when I try to load the csv I get an error: 
`Database error XX000: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT: "(4" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
CONTEXT: COPY crime_data_nyc, line 1, column location: "(40.6227027620001"`

CSV file has the Location column data as `"(40.8037530600001, -73.955861904)"`

Comment: Amend last comment: Point in postgresql as Location's datatype while doing `location = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT')` results in `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function st_asewkb(point) does not exist [...]
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` 
So I assume this is what needs to happen:
Postgresql in create table creates Location column as: `CREATE TABLE  Blah( Location geometry(Point));` and in geoalchemy the type would be `location = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT'))`.

Comment: ```ERROR: geoalchemy2 0.12.3 has requirement SQLAlchemy>=1.4, but you'll have sqlalchemy 1.3.24 which is incompatible.```

Answer (score 3):

You can extend [`UserDefinedType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType) to achieve what you want.

[Here's an example I found](https://gist.github.com/kwatch/02b1a5a8899b67df2623) that gets pretty close to what you want subclassing `UserDefinedType`

Note that [Mohammad Amin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234645/3632543) is valid only if your point is intended to be a geographic point (latitude and longitude constraints). It doesn't apply if you want to represent any point on a plane. Also, in that case you would need to install the PostGIS extension, which I encourage if you are working with geography points as it provides a lot of utlities and extra functions.

Comment: If you don't want to add the PostGIS extension, this is closest to the right answer.  Only issue is that the example is not specifically for the type Point

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example to use a native PostgreSQL [point type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/datatype-geometric.html#DATATYPE-GEOMETRIC-POINTS) in SQLAlchemy without needing PostGIS or other extensions, based on the suggestions made in the other answers:

```python
import sqlalchemy


@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True, slots=True)
class Coordinate:
    """
    Container to hold a geolocation.
    """

    lat: float
    lng: float


class LatLngType(sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType):
    """
    Custom SQLAlchemy type to handle POINT columns.

    References:

    - https://gist.github.com/kwatch/02b1a5a8899b67df2623
    - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType  # noqa
    """

    # Can do because we made the Coordinate dataclass hashable.
    cache_ok = True

    def get_col_spec(self):
        return "POINT"

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return sqlalchemy.func.POINT(bindvalue, type_=self)

    def bind_processor(self, dialect):
        """
        Return function to serialize a Coordinate into a database string literal.
        """

        def process(value: Coordinate | Tuple[float, float] | None) -> str | None:
            if value is None:
                return None

            if isinstance(value, tuple):
                value = Coordinate(*value)

            return f"({value.lat},{value.lng})"

        return process

    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        """
        Return function to parse a database string result into Python data type.
        """

        def process(value: str) -> Coordinate | None:
            if value is None:
                return None

            lat, lng = value.strip("()").split(",")

            return Coordinate(float(lat), float(lng))

        return process
```

Use it as follows:

```python
class MyModel(Base):
    location = Column(LatLngType)
```

Comment: When you're calling `func.POINT` inside `bind_expression`, where is the name `func` coming from? Trying to figure out how this code works, and not sure where you're getting that.

Comment: @josephkibe It's from `sqlalchemy.func`, I made that explicit now...